# Pyintaller Error:pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'setuptools' distribution was not found and is required by the application

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying out to build an executable binary for my python project using Pyinstaller.I can able to build the project successfully.But when I execute the binary it throws below error message.

```
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 48, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "setuptools/package_index.py", line 203, in <module>
File "pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 962, in require
File "pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 849, in resolve
```

pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'setuptools' distribution was not found and is required by the application